# c++ type conversion

Tags: c++

I have a function in C- code based application as given below:

```
void MyFunction(short count, double (*points)[2])
```

I am calling this function with the below parameter types:

```
MyFunction(count, poly_pts);
short count
double *poly_pts
```

Getting compiler error:

```
cannot convert parameter 2 from 'double *' to 'double (*)[2]'
```

I have to pass in the same manner as per the old code. C-code doesn't give any error but c++ compiler gives.

Have anyone any ideas how to convert double pointer to two dimension double pointer?

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question?

Answer (score 1):

The function expects a pointer to an array of 2 `double`s, you only give it a single pointer.

Call it like this:

```
short count;
double points[2];
MyFunction(count, &points);
```

Comment: I have tried as per your comment, but got the same error. wanted to confirm does your solution resolv the below problem:
void write_polygon(short count, double (*points)[2])
{
 //some code
}
void write_one_space_polygon(double *poly_pts, short count)
{
 dwf_write_polygon(count, poly_pts);//error:cannot convert parameter 2 from 'double *' to 'double (*)[2]'
}

Comment: Xeo, I need ur comments on my que.

Answer (score 0):

`double (*points)[2]` is a pointer to an array of 2 elements. What you are passing to the function is actually just a pointer to double. If you want the call to work, you have to actually have an address to an array of 2 doubles. Something like this:

```
double array[2];
myFun(&array);
```

Change the function signature to take `double*` (and possibly another parameter of type `size_t` to indicate the size) or pass an appropriate value to your original function. Note that dynamic allocation of an array returns just a pointer, not a real array.

Comment: Armen, I can't change the function definition of "void MyFunction(short count, double (*points)[2])". 

As per ur comment:
void write_one_space_polygon(double poly_pts[2], short count)
{
 dwf_write_polygon(count, &poly_pts);//error:cannot convert parameter 2 from 'double[]' to 'double (*)[2]'
}

Comment: @Annie: in your example, you have `double (*points)[2]`, not `double (points)[2]`. So, which one is it?

Comment: I am repeating one more time: 
void write_polygon(short count, double (*points)[2]) 
{
  //some code 
} 
void write_one_space_polygon(double *poly_pts, short count) 
{ 
 write_polygon(count, poly_pts);//error:cannot convert parameter 2 from  'double *' to 'double ()[2]' 
}

Comment: @Annie: Look closely, in the code you're getting the error, you've forgotten the `*`

Comment: Is there another way for type casting. Beacuse  write_polygon() is being used in many palces with double pointer parametr. I just want to know type casting from 'double *' to 'double ()[2].